# Búsqueda por fecha y hora en campos separados en Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

tengo una tabla la cual tengo fecha y hora por separado, lo que necesito hacer es buscar registros con fecha y hora anterior al 06/06/2019 23:59:59, pero no se como hacer la query, solo tengo la query para buscar por fecha pero no se como agregarle la hora (lo estoy trabajando en oracle)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE FOLIO='212' AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(FECHA))<=
>   TO_DATE('06/06/2019 23:59:59')

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato son las columnas `fecha` y `hora`?

Comment: @jachguate son de tipo VARCHAR los dos

Comment: Porqué guardar una fecha en string si Oracle dispone del tipo fecha?

Comment: El string de fecha es "dia-mes-año" ó "mes-dia-año"?

Comment: @alvalongo  es dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: ¿Tienes algún motivo en concreto para guardar esta información así? Porque es muchísimo más sencillo trabajar con único campo tipo `DATE`. Si lo que necesitas es convertirlo a cadena de texto puedes usar la función `TO_CHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

Y si a tu consulta lo separas en vez de hacer junto como lo haces te explico, tu lo haces así

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE FOLIO='212' AND TRUNC(TO_DATE(FECHA))<= TO_DATE('06/06/2019 
23:59:59')
```

Por que no lo haces así

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE FOLIO='212' AND TO_DATE(FECHA)<=TO_DATE('06/06/2019)
AND TIME(HORA)<=TIME(23:59:59)
```

Así haces el campo que necesitas con solo la hora y el campo de fecha igual no involucrando la hora en el principal de la fecha.

Saludos

Comment: en este time > TIME(23:59:59) me aparece un error de identificador no valido

Comment: Intenta enviarle la variable tal y como viene sin el Time, creo que depende del valor ya que este ya viene en formato hh:mm:ss